# How to Sum Numbers With Probability

Tags: probability

I have a number of quotes sent to customers to produce widgets. Each quote has a maximum potential quantity and a probability of winning. For example, I have 5 quotes with a quantity and a probability of winning:

```
Q#   Qty    Probability of Winning
----------------------------------
1    1,000  50%
2    5,000  23%
3    4,000  37%
4    2,000  61%
5   10,000  13%
```

I want to show a range of likely qualities needed for planning purposes. The max range is the sum of the qty = 22,000. My question is: what is a reasonable number to show as a minimum (understanding that the min could be zero)? Is sum(qty*p) a reasonable number (5,650)? Other insights would be appreciated.

Comment: $1000\cdot 0.5+5000\cdot .23+4000\cdot .37+\dots$ would be the [*expected number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) of wins, not the minimum.  You could also calculate the [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) using known techniques.

Comment: Having been involved in things like this, I would bet those probabilities are somebody's guess and have little to do with reality.  You can do a number of reasonable calculations, but remember garbage in/garbage out.

Comment: Absolutely! The numbers are pretty much pulled out of the air (or other places). Loosely based on customer relationship and how often a customer selects our widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is each quote "all-or-nothing"?  Does this mean that, e.g. for #1, you get $1000$ with probability $0.50$, and $0$ with probability $0.50$, or is it something else?  If something else, then what?

Assuming independence and "all-or-nothing", the probability of winning nothing is $$(1-0.50)(1-0.23)(1-0.37)(1-0.61)(1-0.13) = 0.082297215$$
I wouldn't call that negligible.  If you do want to neglect it, the next possibility is that you just get $1000$ (i.e. just bid #1), which also has probability $0.082297215$.

Comment: You are correct. It's all or nothing with independence which is what prompted my original question. Thanks for a well reasoned answer. That gives me some more insight.